# Type error: Undefined is not a function (esri map)

Tags: javascript, dojo, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am getting a very strange error after upgrading dojo code to 2.x. The function is defined as:

```
var map; //Globally defined   
Require(["esri/map", "esri/geometry/Point"], function(Map, Point) {    

map = new Map("map", {infoWindow: popupWin, extent: initialExtent, sliderStyle: 'small', sliderPosition: "bottom-right", navigationMode: 'css-transforms'});  
var a = (map.toMap(new Point(0, 0));  
});
```

However, as I execute map.toMap() function in console, it works fine. Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? It's been getting so confusing...

Answer (score 2):

Did you try including [domReady!](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/domReady.html)? It will cause the function to wait untill the DOM is loaded.

```
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(){
    // will not run until DOM is finished loading
});
```

Otherwise it could be that your includes aren't registered yet which you could solve by wrapping your code in [dojo/ready](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/ready.html).

```
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/geometry/Point",
    "dojo/ready"
], function(map, Point, ready){
    ready(function(){
        // This function won't run until the DOM has loaded and other modules that register
    });
});
```

Comment: Can I pass it like this?  Require(["esri/map", "esri/geometry/Point", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(Map, Point) {} or I need to include "domReady!" in a separate require?

Comment: That would be fine. Also note that there is no need to pass it to the function as a parameter because it's a plugin. Because of that it's good practice to add plugins at the end of your require array.

Comment: Ok, then there's something else you can try, i'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I can send you the detailed of my function. Since it is kinda long, I avoided to put it here

Comment: I have already tried "dojo/ready". The page stops loading just before ready(function(){}); happens

Comment: Sending stuff privately is not how StackOverflow works, if it's too much for posting here, you could always create a testcase on plunker to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: The error is gone. I just had to rearrange the variables and define the point before calling it in toMap() function.